# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - no sound control panel?

Tags: speakers

I'm trying to play sound over a bluetooth connection to a Bose Soundlink Mini. I've succeeded in pairing, but have no idea how to select the Mini as output. I've tried all sorts of things but being a total newb I've killed ALL sound...

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Sound icon on the unity bar 
Select **sound settings**
Under the **Output** tab , you will see a list named **Play Sound Through**
There select  your desired output device
Hope this helps. If you have a different problem , please mention it.